# Select data from sql with result multiple count

Tags: sql

I need a help. 
I want to select data from SQL like this. Total is the result of `count(*) * 7500`.

```
| fullname | count(*) | total |
+==========+==========+=======+
| angelis  | 3        | 22500 |
| freed    | 2        | 14000 |
| debora   | 4        | 28500 |
```

I use query like this

```
select fullname, count(*) as jml 
from pms_occupancy 
where month(date)='02' 
group by fullname
```

and it shows

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with your query?

Comment: can you send sample table structure..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to find your required output in SQL SERVER :

**Sample Table structure**

```
=================
ID  |   Country
=================
1   |   C1
2   |   C2
3   |   C3
4   |   C4
=================
```

**Required Query:**

```
declare @result_string varchar(max)=''
;WITH CTE_TABLE 
AS
(
SELECT ID,Country FROM dbo.tblCountry
)
select @result_string=@result_string+'<tr><td>'+(cast(ID as varchar(100))+'</td><td>'+Country+'</td></tr>') from (
SELECT * FROM CTE_TABLE
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) ID,'Total' Country FROM CTE_TABLE
)a

select '<table>'+@result_string+'</table>'
```

**Output of query**

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>C1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>C2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>C3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>C4</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Total</td></tr>
</table>
```